# JanusGraph hangs with properties >1kB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, janusgraph

I have a Java application using JanusGraph with a DynamoDB backend. Whenever I try to commit a property greater than 1kB, the transaction hangs and never returns, and does not seem to be generating any error messages. How do I fix this? I have tried changing many JanusGraph settings, including storage.buffer-size.